# sql server: An expression of non-boolean type specified in context where a condition is expected

Tags: sql-server

I execute this code in postgresql and it runs fine.

```
SELECT t.anonymous_id AS anonym_id, 
    (select event_name 
        from tracks t1 
            where t1.anonymous_id = t.anonymous_id and user_id is null order by received_at desc limit 1) as last_null, 
    (select event_name 
        from tracks t2 
            where t2.anonymous_id = t.anonymous_id and user_id is not null ) as first_notnull
FROM tracks t
GROUP BY anonym_id
ORDER BY anonym_id;
```

Then I write it again in sql server and got some errors. After trying to fix, my code look like this:

```
SELECT t.anonymous_id AS anonym_id 
FROM tracks t
JOIN
    (select event_name 
        from tracks t1 
            where t1.anonymous_id = anonymous_id and user_id is null order by received_at desc offset 0 rows) as last_null, 
    (select event_name 
        from tracks t2 
            where t2.anonymous_id = anonymous_id and user_id is not null) as first_notnull
GROUP BY anonym_id
ORDER BY anonym_id;
```

Currently, I got an error

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in context where a condition is expected near ','
```

Why? And how to fix that?

Comment: SQL Server does not support `LIMIT`, it uses `TOP`, with a fairly different syntax.  What is your actual database?

Comment: You can't just copy SQL from one RDBMS and then paste it into another and expect it to work. They all use different dialects. YOu have to "translate" it from one dialect to the other. Your `JOIN` to your subquery `last_null` is missing an `ON`, and then you're using that old ANSI-89 JOIN syntax for `first_notnull`

Comment: Why the re-write to a JOIN?  If you use `top ..` instead of `limit` in the first query, that should work with SQL Server as well

Comment: Those subqueries, however, are in the `SELECT` in your PostgreSQL query. Why have they migrated to the `FROM` in your T-SQL query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I replace limit by using offset. My actual database is sql server. I think my problem is using join to subquery as Larnu answer